# DevMode not showing detailed Internal 500 Errors

Tags: php, error, devmode

I've noticed lately, maybe after the last Craft update or two, that internal 500 errors no longer show information or error traces. I simply get a message like:

```
Internal Server Error
Undefined offset: 0
```

And that's all it will show. I've checked that devmode is set to true, and in dashboard it shows that devmode is on. Is there a particular reason this would be happening? Maybe because the error is coming from a plugin and not twig? Or a general setting I'm not aware of for more detailed errors? It used to show all the information I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed this was a regression with the Yii 1.1.16/Craft 2.4 update and it's been fixed for the next [post 2.4.2670](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2670) update.